# Firebase database not getting updated when updating it from intent service

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, intentservice

I have created a background intent service to update data in the firebase database. 
When my application is in foreground, the data is updated properly. But when my application is killed, the data is not updated in the firebase database.

Service declare in manifest file

```
 <service
        android:name=".service.MyIntentService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"></service>
```

The Intent service class that works properly when my app is in the foreground but not when the app is in the background.

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.softwebsolutions.datetime.DateTime;
import com.softwebsolutions.devicemanagement.bean.WifiStatus;
import com.softwebsolutions.devicemanagement.utils.Utility;

/**
 * An {@link IntentService} subclass for handling asynchronous task requests in
 * a service on a separate handler thread.
 * <p>
 * TODO: Customize class - update intent actions, extra parameters and static
 * helper methods.
 */
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {
  // TODO: Rename actions, choose action names that describe tasks that this
  // IntentService can perform, e.g. ACTION_FETCH_NEW_ITEMS
  private static final String ACTION_FOO =
      "com.softwebsolutions.devicemanagement.service.action.FOO";
  private static final String ACTION_BAZ =
      "com.softwebsolutions.devicemanagement.service.action.BAZ";

  // TODO: Rename parameters
  private static final String EXTRA_PARAM1 =
      "com.softwebsolutions.devicemanagement.service.extra.PARAM1";
  private static final String EXTRA_PARAM2 =
      "com.softwebsolutions.devicemanagement.service.extra.PARAM2";
  private static final String EXTRA_PARAM3 =
      "com.softwebsolutions.devicemanagement.service.extra.PARAM3";
  private static final String TAG = MyIntentService.class.getSimpleName();

  public MyIntentService() {
    super("MyIntentService");
  }

  // TODO: Customize helper method
  public static void startActionFoo(Context context, String param1, String param2, String param3) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_FOO);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM1, param1);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM2, param2);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM3, param3);
    context.startService(intent);
  }

  @Override protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
      final String action = intent.getAction();
      final String wifiMac = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PARAM1);
      final String strSSID = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PARAM2);
      final String macAddress = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PARAM3);
      handleActionFoo(wifiMac, strSSID, macAddress, getApplicationContext());
    }
  }


  private void handleActionFoo(final String wifiMac, final String strSSID,
      final String macAddress, final Context context) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onReceive.......service........");
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseTmp =
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Android").child("wifiList").child(wifiMac);

    mDatabaseTmp.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onReceive.......addValueEventListener");
        if (dataSnapshot != null) {
          Log.e(TAG, "onReceive.......dataSnapshot...NOT NULL");
          String floorName = "Not detect";
          if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
            floorName = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            Log.e(TAG, "onReceive: ----------->" + floorName);
          }
        }
      }

      @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }
    });

    mDatabaseTmp.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onReceive.......dataSnapshot...");
        if (dataSnapshot != null) {
          Log.e(TAG, "onReceive.......dataSnapshot...NOT NULL");
          String floorName = "Not detect";
          if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
            floorName = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
          }

          String currentDate =
              DateTime.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime(" yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSS'Z'");
          Log.e(TAG, "onReceive.......dataSnapshot..."
              + currentDate
              + " Floor Name -------->"
              + floorName);

          String deviceId = Utility.getDeviceID(context);

          WifiStatus wifiStatus = new WifiStatus();
          wifiStatus.setDeviceId(deviceId);
          wifiStatus.setName(strSSID);
          wifiStatus.setMacAddress(macAddress);
          wifiStatus.setDate(currentDate);
          wifiStatus.setStatus(WifiStatus.STATUS_CONNECTED);
          wifiStatus.setFloorName(floorName);

          Utility.updateWifiStatus(context, wifiStatus);
        } else {
          Log.e(TAG, "onReceive.......dataSnapshot...NULL");
        }
      }

      @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Service classes extend the Context class. Instead of passing `getApplicationContext()` to the `handleActionFoo` method, you should pass `MyIntentService.this`.

Comment: I have also passed service context still it's not working @RosárioPereiraFernandes

Answer (score 1):

An [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) only stays active for as long as it takes handleIntent() to service the next intent, and there are no more pending intents.  You can think of each intent as a "command" to the service, and it will run for as long as it takes that command to complete.  When the last command is done, it stops itself.  As such, it does not typically stay running for very long.  If you're expecting an IntentService to stay running for a long time, you probably don't want to be using an IntentService at all.

Also, Android Services don't care if the app is in the foreground (visible) or background (invisible).  They can be started and stopped regardless.  The process that hosts the app may stay running indefinitely.

You haven't really stated what you're trying to accomplish with this service, so it's impossible to say what you should be doing instead.  If you want a listener to be active for as long as the service is "started", then IntentService is not the right tool.  You should look into a custom implementation.